# targeting li on hover but not parent li

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have a dynamically generated list that has potentially up to about 5 levels. I want the listed item text to underline when I hover over the listed item, however not the parent li.

see example.

http://jsfiddle.net/ca7fL/5/

you see when you hover on "this", the above parent li, underlines aswell.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: If you have an li with no children, should that underline when hovered over?

Comment: no that doesn't need to underline

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That seems hard to achieve, since when you point the child `li` element you're also effectively pointing its parent.

There is a solution, though: add a `span` tag to your menu items, and make that tag hoverable: http://jsfiddle.net/ca7fL/16/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to apply css classes to LI - Elements when geenerating them, so you can style them explicitly. CSS itself seems to be insufficient here.

Answer (score -1):

```
ul li ul { padding-left:20px}
ul li ul li:hover { text-decoration:underline; curor:pointer;}
```

Comment: This disables the effect for the top level `li`. I don't think that's what he wants.

Comment: this one removes :hover-formatting from "ul li", which is also needed.

Comment: Also, it will not work as required if the list is nested on more levels (the OP mentions up to 5).